# Ошибка описания шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, динамические-массивы

DynamicMassives.h

```
//------------------------------------------------------------- create simple massive
template <typename T>
T * getArray(int &len) {        // returns pointer to dynamic massive
    T *ptr;

    if (!(ptr = new T[len])) {  // conditional of possibility of memory allocation
        cout << "can't allocate memory..." << endl;
        return nullptr;             // protection if there is no memory rest
    }
    else return ptr;
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>    // for random
#include "DynamicMassives.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));  // randomize

    //----------------------------------------------- Simple dynamic massive
    cout << "simple dynamic massive:" << endl;
    int *parr;      // pointer for dynamic massive
    int len = 20;   // length of dynamic massive

    parr = getArray(len);   // call for dynamic massive creating function <<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR!!!!

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Вывод:

> Ошибка    C2672   "getArray": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция
>   Ошибка    C2783   T *getArray(int &): не удается составить аргумент шаблон для "T"

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так с шаблоном? Без шаблона с интом везде работала отлично.

Comment: Что-то странное у вас тут написано. `int &len` Какой смысл передавать длину по ссылке? `!(ptr = new T[len])` по умолчанию new бросает исключение, если не смог выделит память. До проверки на ноль дело не дойдет. Вам нужен `std::nothrow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно явно указать тип для элементов, хранящихся в массиве:

```
parr = getArray<int>(len);
```

Далее:

```
if (!(ptr = new T[len])) {
    cout << "can't allocate memory..." << endl;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Поведение оператора `new` отлично от поведения функции `malloc` - если по каким-то причинам память не может быть выделена - будет выброшено исключение. Т.о., в C Вы можете использовать подобную конструкцию, а в C++ - нет:

```
// OK
int* arr;
if (!(arr = (int*)malloc(...)) { ... }

// Неверно
int* arr;
if (!(arr = new int[...])) { ... }
```

Пример ф-ии в которой тип выводится из ее аргумента:

```
template<typename T>
auto sum(T _l, T _r) -> decltype(_l + _r) { return _l + _r; }
```

В ф-ии из Вашего примера тип не может быть выведен автоматически - т.к. в качестве аргумента Вы используете число, характеризующее *число элементов* в массиве, но никак не *тип* этих элементов.

Comment: @Григорий, рад помочь!